# How to solve "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables" in cross validation

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, cross-validation, forecasting

When I am doing neural nets, I want to use cross-validation to determine the number of neurons used in a layer. Here is the web page I referred: https://www.r-bloggers.com/selecting-the-number-of-neurons-in-the-hidden-layer-of-a-neural-network/

My code is as below:

```
max.train = apply(train[,-c(1,2)], 2 , max)
min.train = apply(train[,-c(1,2)], 2 , min)
trainNN = as.data.frame(scale(train[,-c(1,2)], center = min.train, scale = max.train - min.train))
max.test = apply(test[,-c(1,2)], 2 , max)
min.test = apply(test[,-c(1,2)], 2 , min)
testNN = as.data.frame(scale(test[,-c(1,2)], center = min.test, scale = max.test - min.test))
maxs <- apply(corn[,-c(1,2)], 2, max) 
mins <- apply(corn[,-c(1,2)], 2, min)
scaled = as.data.frame(scale(corn[,-c(1,2)], center = mins, scale = maxs - mins))

crossvalidate <- function(data,hidden_l=c(5))
{
  cv.error <- NULL
  k <- 10

  for(j in 1:k)
  {
    nn <- neuralnet(lprice ~ volume+open_interest, data=trainNN, hidden=hidden_l, linear.output=T)
    pr.nn <- compute(nn, testNN[,1:2])
    pr.nn <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(data$lprice)-min(data$lprice))+min(data$lprice)
    test.cv.r <- (testNN$lprice)*(max(data$lprice)-min(data$lprice))+min(data$lprice)
    cv.error[j] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn)^2)/nrow(testNN)
  }
  return(mean(cv.error))
}

test.error <- NULL
train.error <- NULL
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(5)

set.seed(100)
for(i in 1:5)
{
  # Fit the net and calculate training error (point estimate)
  nn <- neuralnet(lprice ~ volume + open_interest, data=scaled, hidden=c(i), linear.output=T)
  train.error[i] <- sum(((as.data.frame(nn$net.result)*(7.880 - 7.129) + 7.129) - (scaled$lprice*(7.880 - 7.129) + 7.129))^2)/nrow(scaled)

  # Calculate test error through cross validation
  test.error[i] <- crossvalidate(corn, hidden_l=c(i))

  # Step bar
  pbar$step()
}
```

The difference between his code and mine is that I only have two predictors: volume and open interest. I need to predict the corn price in 2018 so I just took the data in 2018 as test data and the data before 2018 as training data. I divided the total dataset before the loop.

The data looks like this and the testNN and scaled dataset are similar. There is no NA in the three datasets and the original corn dataset and the three variables are all numeric.

```
 - head(trainNN)
 - volume   open_interest lprice
 - 1 0.007069       0.03093   0.4043
 - 2 0.011904       0.03133   0.4921 
 - 3 0.011351       0.03193   0.4691

summary(trainNN)
     volume       open_interest        lprice     
 Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :0.000  
 1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:0.0003   1st Qu.:0.346  
 Median :0.0003   Median :0.0057   Median :0.516  
 Mean   :0.0144   Mean   :0.0462   Mean   :0.550  
 3rd Qu.:0.0035   3rd Qu.:0.0423   3rd Qu.:0.829  
 Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :1.000
```

But the loop does not work well and keep popping the error

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables
>
> > In addition: Warning message:
> >     Algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax.

Why does the problem appear and how to solve it?

Here are the details of my datasets:

```
dput(head(trainNN, 50))
structure(list(volume = c(0.00120479469333848, 0.000129847003131168, 
0.000733635567691098, 7.41982875035244e-06, 0.000944173208482348, 
0.00105083324676866, 0.0157161247718403, 3.70991437517622e-06, 
4.17365367207325e-05, 4.63739296897028e-06, 1.57671360944989e-05, 
0.000153961446569813, 8.81104664104353e-05, 4.17365367207325e-05, 
0.00331944588718892, 0.0045400077166219, 0.00387500556487156, 
0.000345949515485183, 0.000164163711101548, 0.00201819342009586, 
0.00236043302120587, 0.01444733405553, 0.00250604716043154, 2.31869648448514e-05, 
4.54464510959087e-05, 0, 9.27478593794055e-07, 0.00279356552450769, 
0.00255242109012124, 0.00196347218306201, 1.02022645317346e-05, 
0.00217957469541603, 0.00106845534005075, 4.08090581269384e-05, 
0.000232797127042308, 7.79082018787006e-05, 0.00519944499680947, 
0.00792437710537641, 0.00630963687358096, 0.000309777850327214, 
4.35914939083206e-05, 0.00141440485553593, 0.00513637645243148, 
0.125604716043154, 1.85495718758811e-05, 2.87518364076157e-05, 
8.3473073441465e-06, 0.000630685443779958, 0.0135903438348643, 
0.000255056613293365), open_interest = c(0.0197915558864192, 
0.00123364883547804, 0.0172950122301393, 2.65872593853026e-06, 
0.0139383707327449, 0.0200973093693502, 0.119931138998192, 0.00937466765925768, 
0.00381261299585239, 0.0039495373816867, 0.00020738062320536, 
0.000312400297777305, 0.0220022865043071, 0.000390832712963948, 
0.0272785281293204, 0.101016962671488, 0.0195509411889822, 0.00858901414442199, 
0.00559794746357545, 0.0130822609805381, 0.0132510900776348, 
0.215476443688185, 0.000724502818249495, 0.000316388386685101, 
0.000623471232585345, 5.58332447091354e-05, 5.45038817398703e-05, 
0.0573593533978517, 0.0156466021482506, 0.0447742741678188, 0.000305753482930979, 
0.00769036477719877, 0.0141523981707966, 0.000405455705625864, 
0.016496065085611, 0, 0.0187905455705626, 0.0804849516111879, 
0.00265739657556099, 0.012168988620653, 0.000519780920982665, 
0.0012389662873551, 0.0188370732744869, 0.291452196107625, 0.000623471232585345, 
0.00173348931192173, 0.000214027438051686, 0.0177616186323514, 
0.133994469850048, 0.00653116026799957), lprice = c(0.510582301463774, 
0.344204416537943, 0.851462133609609, 0.340903299172643, 0.895773917944989, 
0.356511250391288, 0.847513792278632, 0.31672235023017, 0.652594661043185, 
0.412485880130917, 0.806208151506684, 0.688082354441166, 0.346674896705426, 
0.868252274097258, 0.933373193480856, 0.859883659081866, 0.0987118318873677, 
0.648009457977949, 0.187832453779507, 0.383192570887849, 0.332614534559063, 
0.885931507335992, 0.688718913676761, 0.520006015479584, 0.372745457136178, 
0.552826105439045, 0.588978642534753, 0.350782208548046, 0.77436599354315, 
0.854837135858998, 0.74296653001429, 0.367085963811137, 0.909863554831568, 
0.294663244451221, 0.333445735943372, 0.420293640910594, 0.0957352939445262, 
0.367085963811137, 0.674643852907022, 0.301489653627575, 0.681060051128024, 
0.667550153291217, 0.946548376814812, 0.478927864832375, 0.373551996776401, 
0.845818056626141, 0.804458971773855, 0.845252331336205, 0.401477551563487, 
0.250302625671116)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(testNN, 50))
structure(list(volume = c(0.00706941956640145, 0.0119040265931462, 
0.0113509385651156, 0.0120303664980263, 0.0186702303878354, 0.0126424131483343, 
0.0311834960778478, 0.0338506718475386, 0.0241561898130731, 0.0330027907081211, 
0.026809327815555, 0.0260035599777642, 0.0319892639156386, 0.0265089195972845, 
0.0357401553138564, 0.0365683835791814, 0.035324637404473, 0.049780730076197, 
0.0364532738880685, 0.0490311133072418, 0.0276179032067875, 0.0210566508133482, 
0.00746247704825061, 0.00181648707683151, 0.00219831434491356, 
0.000401480142174506, 0.00295073866731053, 0.000188106080599244, 
0, 0.000126339904880089, 0.0021084726347766, 0.000345329073338911, 
0.000188106080599244, 0.0019287892145027, 0.0135520604634709, 
0.00230500137570119, 0.00889432930355829, 0.553716920001572, 
0.839989106692646, 0.951370366834933, 0.581725073136767, 0.638128821782123, 
0.751267610378964, 0.441645001712608, 0.442015598766923, 0.320864052647242, 
0.251806660639785, 0.470905323682836, 0.315720614741902, 0.344082519610761
), open_interest = c(0.0309283824075963, 0.0313335699255852, 
0.0319315708142034, 0.0374477098522044, 0.0445175334419422, 0.0438049622896169, 
0.0440704299738165, 0.0444728230951296, 0.0423099600680715, 0.0331080118147091, 
0.0335383489027801, 0.0305092229062284, 0.0273655266459695, 0.0261220201252449, 
0.0255910847568456, 0.0254457761297047, 0.0257056550205528, 0.0256888886404981, 
0.0256721222604434, 0.0255715239801151, 0.0259739171014282, 0.0258817020111273, 
0.025663739070416, 0.0238865027846163, 0.0170486141189686, 0.0170402309289413, 
0.0153188825766573, 0.00794446974925879, 0.000502991401641429, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.930472616309776, 0.877066107042159, 
0.811900776562836, 0.775534498224161, 0.769792013055421, 0.714309267057696, 
0.628929271025739, 0.514769783629865, 0.481555584741476, 0.455000433131485, 
0.436155021949986, 0.415213813261648, 0.364766570073688), lprice = c(0.404330074913638, 
0.492083022366336, 0.469079773268984, 0.619738346603267, 0.60162141297546, 
0.610684813595797, 0.60615434808141, 0.510439915573559, 0.542467292012032, 
0.597086005584079, 0.588007763147557, 0.556155639540664, 0.528756375062575, 
0.469079773268984, 0.487487460356058, 0.413610956731874, 0.418247516230837, 
0.455247217965267, 0.446012714799772, 0.422881491968453, 0.413610956731874, 
0.408971810588703, 0.446012714799772, 0.446012714799772, 0.455247217965267, 
0.455247217965267, 0.487487460356058, 0.459860626819221, 0.469079773268984, 
0.459860626819221, 0.455247217965267, 0.44139161479424, 0.469079773268984, 
0.473685516530432, 0.578919599132632, 0.588007763147557, 0.727618812006047, 
0.574371789751591, 0.628782033460881, 0.758822110329113, 0.794340239055759, 
0.705258838205934, 0.646839954229117, 0.592548123209006, 0.537899497749437, 
0.551595360157961, 0.528756375062575, 0.473685516530432, 0.551595360157961, 
0.510439915573559)), row.names = c(NA, 50L), class = "data.frame")

dput(head(scaled, 50))
structure(list(volume = c(0.000115934824224257, 0.00039788831673765, 
2.13320076572633e-05, 8.3473073441465e-06, 1.57671360944989e-05, 
8.3473073441465e-06, 0.000161381275320166, 3.70991437517622e-06, 
9.83127309421699e-05, 2.78243578138217e-05, 7.41982875035244e-06, 
0.000156743882351195, 1.39121789069108e-05, 0.000120572217193227, 
0.000115934824224257, 0.000556487156276433, 5.19388012524671e-05, 
0.000217957469541603, 0.000238361998605072, 0.000139121789069108, 
0.000301430542983068, 4.82288868772909e-05, 4.63739296897028e-05, 
2.22594862510573e-05, 6.86334159407601e-05, 0.000283808449700981, 
0.000370991437517622, 7.14158517221423e-05, 0.000189205633133987, 
0.000209610162197456, 0.000160453796726372, 8.81104664104353e-05, 
1.85495718758811e-05, 9.27478593794055e-06, 0.000182713282977429, 
0.00231962396307893, 0.00387500556487156, 0.00414119192129046, 
0.00555003190526363, 0.00519944499680947, 0.00395105880956268, 
0.00168059121195483, 0.000386758573612121, 0.00250511968183774, 
0.00169543086945553, 0.00119273747161916, 0.00142275216288008, 
0.00146541617819461, 0.000398815795331444, 0.000248564263136807
), open_interest = c(0.002306444751675, 0.0023024566627672, 0.00229713921089014, 
0.00229182175901308, 0.00228916303307455, 0.00228916303307455, 
0.00222934169945762, 0.00222934169945762, 0.00214293310645539, 
0.00211767521003935, 0.00210704030628523, 0.0020738062320536, 
0.00206848878017654, 0.00195416356481974, 0.0019023184090184, 
0.00178001701584601, 0.00174678294161438, 0.00166037434861215, 
0.00171487823035202, 0.00169094969690524, 0.00157396575560991, 
0.00157396575560991, 0.00156731894076359, 0.00157130702967138, 
0.00154870785919387, 0.00155003722216314, 0.0011778155907689, 
0.00114458151653728, 0.0010063277677337, 0.00113793470169095, 
0.00118845049452302, 0.00114192279059875, 0.00112597043496756, 
0.00112198234605977, 0.000962458789747953, 0.0208909390620015, 
0.0195509411889822, 0.019484473040519, 0.019354195469531, 0.0187905455705626, 
0.0171142188663193, 0.0163338828033606, 0.0161557481654791, 0.0155362650218016, 
0.0151215037753908, 0.0143584494310326, 0.0133880144634691, 0.0119376794640009, 
0.0117622035520579, 0.0116146442624694), lprice = c(0.0159141698893206, 
0.0085112121866148, 0.0116889477100056, 0.01063054465461, 0.00745028009139348, 
0.00745028009139348, 0.00957129992671682, 0.00638850229493165, 
0.00957129992671682, 0.00213290706124252, 0, 0.00638850229493165, 
0.00106688045361737, 0.0085112121866148, 0.00213290706124252, 
0.0243246172486233, 0.0232762109173386, 0.0337233246690091, 0.0807520068767474, 
0.067628746289212, 0.0358029506576186, 0.043056178402089, 0.0625467096965389, 
0.0502701234826566, 0.067628746289212, 0.0615279714632226, 0.0645818516892853, 
0.0574452091092523, 0.067628746289212, 0.0482129799461532, 0.0767278341025268, 
0.0767278341025268, 0.0543749038501801, 0.0553991254885964, 0.0666138889638279, 
0.0997025349268141, 0.0987118318873677, 0.105631328877444, 0.100692501657728, 
0.0957352939445262, 0.0817561533058562, 0.0827595433157385, 0.0747111794021993, 
0.0797471028870763, 0.0696561442074541, 0.0737017059358222, 0.0716804609726562, 
0.0615279714632226, 0.0605084534837667, 0.0594881545636145)), row.names = c(NA, 
50L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please check whether your dataset contains some non-numeric inputs like NA using `summary()`

Comment: you can provide part of the data using dput() so that we can run ourselves this thing and see what is going on. however it seems to me that you may have to coerse a factor or a string to numeric

Comment: Consider using the `caret` package for all of this. [Take a look at the manual for caret](http://topepo.github.io/caret/index.html), specifically at model tuning. Will save you time and make your code look neater.

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos  The datasets are very large and when I use dput() there are so many numbers. It is hard for me to paste them here. The three variables are all numeric and I updated the summary of the three datasets. Will it help?

Comment: @BappaDas Thanks for the advice but I checked my variables are all numeric and there is no NA.

Comment: @csgroen Thank you! Will take a look.

Comment: is it possible to do dput(head(yourdata, 50)) ?

Comment: @DimitriosZacharatos  I updated the code above. Is it OK?

Comment: @AdeleTong for `neuralnet`, it is better to create model formula first then use it. See my answer.

Comment: The problem is that during creation of `crossvalidate` function you are using `data=trainNN` but during applying the function you are using `data=scaled`. It should be same.

Comment: this is brilliant. as you can see this allows people to provide an answer you and helps you.

Comment: @BappaDas It finally works! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(neuralnet)
scaled = dput(head(trainNN, 50))
n <- names(scaled)
f <- as.formula(paste("lprice ~", paste(n[!n %in% "lprice"], collapse = " + ")))

set.seed(450)
cv.error <- NULL
k <- 10

library(plyr) 
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(k)

for(i in 1:k){
  index <- sample(1:nrow(scaled),round(0.9*nrow(scaled)))
  train.cv <- scaled[index,]
  test.cv <- scaled[-index,]

  nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train.cv,hidden=c(5),linear.output=T)

  pr.nn <- predict(nn,test.cv)
  pr.nn <- pr.nn*(max(scaled$lprice)-min(scaled$lprice))+min(scaled$lprice)

  test.cv.r <- (test.cv$lprice)*(max(scaled$lprice)-min(scaled$lprice))+min(scaled$lprice)

  cv.error[i] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn)^2)/nrow(test.cv)

  pbar$step()
}

mean(cv.error)
cv.error
plot(nn)
```

If you want to correct your code then see following

```
library(plyr)
library(neuralnet)
scaled = dput(head(trainNN, 50))
n <- names(scaled)
f <- as.formula(paste("lprice ~", paste(n[!n %in% "lprice"], collapse = " + ")))

crossvalidate <- function(data,hidden_l=c(5))
{
  # Initialize cv.error vector
  cv.error <- NULL

  # Number of train-test splits
  k <- 10

  # Cross validating
  for(j in 1:k)
  {
    # Train-test split
    index <- sample(1:nrow(scaled),round(0.90*nrow(scaled)))
    train.cv <- scaled[index,]
    test.cv <- scaled[-index,]

    # NN fitting
    nn <- neuralnet(f,data=train.cv,hidden=hidden_l,linear.output=T)

    # Predicting
    pr.nn <- compute(nn,test.cv)

    # Scaling back the predicted results
    pr.nn <- pr.nn$net.result*(max(scaled$lprice)-min(scaled$lprice))+min(scaled$lprice)

    # Real results
    test.cv.r <- (test.cv$lprice)*(max(scaled$lprice)-min(scaled$lprice))+min(scaled$lprice)

    # Calculating MSE test error
    cv.error[j] <- sum((test.cv.r - pr.nn)^2)/nrow(test.cv)
  }

  # Return average MSE
  return(mean(cv.error))
}

n <- names(scaled)
f <- as.formula(paste("lprice ~", paste(n[!n %in% "lprice"], collapse = " + ")))

# Generate progress bar
pbar <- create_progress_bar('text')
pbar$init(13)

set.seed(100)
# Testing and Cross validating (may take a while to compute)
for(i in 1:13)
{
  # Fit the net and calculate training error (point estimate)
  nn <- neuralnet(f,data=scaled,hidden=c(i),linear.output=T)
  train.error[i] <- sum(((as.data.frame(nn$net.result)*(7.880 - 7.129) + 7.129) - (scaled$lprice*(7.880 - 7.129) + 7.129))^2)/nrow(scaled)

  # Calculate test error through cross validation
  test.error[i] <- crossvalidate(scaled,hidden_l=c(i))

  # Step bar
  pbar$step()
}
test.error
train.error

# Plot train error
plot(train.error,main='MSE vs hidden neurons',xlab="Hidden neurons",ylab='Train error MSE',type='l',col='red',lwd=2)
# Plot test error
plot(test.error,main='MSE vs hidden neurons',xlab="Hidden neurons",ylab='Test error MSE',type='l',col='blue',lwd=2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but it still can't work... The error is the same as above.

Comment: Using the data (`scaled = dput(head(trainNN, 50))`) you have provided, I am not getting any error. I have updated my answer. Do not make so many operations before applying the code on the data as you have done in your question.